# Laravel / LiveWire : Uncaught TypeError: initialData is null

Tags: laravel-livewire

I've been having a problem for several days with a Livewire component on a Laravel project and I must admit I'm a bit lost.

My problem is that I have this error Uncaught TypeError: initialData is null, but I don't understand how I can fix it.

Could someone please help or at least enlighten me?

What I'd like to do is, when I get to my events page, display all my events. And when I filter, I want to display only the filtered data. Currently, I have the filtered data displayed at the top, then the filter bar and finally the original data (all events).
I realized while inspecting that I already had two hands in the dom, the first the filtered elements, the second the original elements).

Extract of the form with wire attributes:

```
<form id="filterbar" wire:submit.prevent="applyFilters" class="px-8 py-4 flex flex-wrap w-full bg-white justify-center">

<button type="submit" id="filterButon" wire:click='applyFilters' onclick="console.log('Clicked!')">Appliquer les filtres</button>
```

Extract of Filterbar to launch an event :

```
public function applyFilters()
    {
        // Récupérer les valeurs sélectionnées des filtres et les émettre via un événement Livewire
        $this->emit('filtersApplied', [
            'selectedStructure' => $this->selectedStructure,
            'selectedParticipant' => $this->selectedParticipant,
            'selectedDateStart' => $this->selectedDateStart,
            'selectedDateEnd' => $this->selectedDateEnd,
            'selectedAccessType' => $this->selectedAccessType,
            'selectedTags' => $this->checkedTags,
        ]);
    }
```

The filtering part of the EventList component:

```
    protected $listeners = ['filtersApplied' => 'applyFilters'];

public function applyFilters($selectedFilters)
    {
        $this->filters = $selectedFilters;
        $this->filterEvents();
    }

    public function filterEvents()
    {
        $today = now();
        $query = Event::with('structure', 'number_of_participants', 'accessType')
            ->has('structure')
            ->has('number_of_participants')
            ->has('accessType')
            ->has('tags')
            ->orderBy('date_start', 'asc');

        if (isset($this->filters['selectedStructure'])) {
            $query->where('structure_id', $this->filters['selectedStructure']);
        }

        if (isset($this->filters['selectedDateStart']) && isset($this->filters['selectedDateEnd'])) {
            $query->where('date_start', '>=', $this->filters['selectedDateStart'])
                ->where('date_end', '<=', $this->filters['selectedDateEnd']);
        } elseif (isset($this->filters['selectedDateStart'])) {
            $query->where('date_start', '=', $this->filters['selectedDateStart']);
        } elseif (isset($this->filters['selectedDateEnd'])) {
            $query->where('date_end', '=', $this->filters['selectedDateEnd']);
        } else {
            $query->where('date_start', '>=', $today);
        }

        $query->orderBy('date_start', 'asc');
        $this->filteredEvents = $query->get();

        $this->events = $this->filteredEvents;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $eventsToDisplay = !empty($this->filters) ? $this->filteredEvents : $this->events;

        return view('livewire.event-list', ['events' => $eventsToDisplay]);
    }
```

extract from the associated view :

```
<x-app-layout>
  <x-slot name="header">
     <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight ml-4"> {{ __('Liste des événements') }}</h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div>
        @if($events->isEmpty())
        <div class="p-8 border-2 w-3/4 mb-6 mx-auto">
            <p class="">Aucun événement trouvé.</p>
        </div>
        @else
        @foreach($events as $event)
         ... ... ...
        @endforeach
        @endif
    </div>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/deleteModal.js') }}"></script>
</x-app-layout>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please provide a reduced code sample with your error?
Then it's easier to understand your problem and point you to the right solution. Right now it's too much code to read and understand.

Comment: Is everything in a single root div? You have `@livewireStyles` and `@livewireScripts` loaded in? Are any nested components set with a `wire:key`?

Comment: Hi @Sergej Tihonov, I've made the code concise enough to make it clearer.

Comment: The @livewireStyle and srcipt are loaded in my app.blade.php. I don't use wire:key ans my root div is div wire:id=events